# how can I resolve the "undefined columns selected" error for ggforest

Tags: r, survival, survminer

How can I resolve the error of undefined columns selected? I have loaded the survminer and the survival packages.

```
   cox4<- coxph(formula= Surv(LOS,Mortality)~ BNPcat+HF_dx+Age+Sex+BMI+
           Admit_QTc+FI02_comb+Admit_Lactate,data=DF)
    ggforest(cox4)
```

```
> cox4
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(LOS, Mortality) ~ BNPcat + HF_dx + Age + 
    Sex + BMI + Admit_QTc + FI02_comb + Admit_Lactate, data = DF)

                    coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z      p
BNPcat1        0.9030311  2.4670696  0.9888592  0.913 0.3611
HF_dx1         0.8819918  2.4157065  0.8519562  1.035 0.3005
Age            0.0479344  1.0491018  0.0284893  1.683 0.0925
Sex1           0.3792915  1.4612490  0.7020620  0.540 0.5890
BMI            0.0250854  1.0254027  0.0319454  0.785 0.4323
Admit_QTc     -0.0006391  0.9993611  0.0060206 -0.106 0.9155
FI02_comb      0.0204957  1.0207072  0.0101321  2.023 0.0431
Admit_Lactate  0.2433651  1.2755342  0.1112036  2.188 0.0286

Likelihood ratio test=21.33  on 8 df, p=0.006311
n= 71, number of events= 13 
   (62 observations deleted due to missingness)
> ggforest(cox4)
Error in `[.data.frame`(cbind(allTermsDF, coef[inds, ]), , c("var", "level",  : 
  undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In .get_data(model, data = data) :
  The `data` argument is not provided. Data will be extracted from model fit.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to confirm the source of the error without seeing either the data or the model summary, but if we do this:

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)

data <- data.frame(LOS = rlnorm(1000, rep(0:1, each = 500)),
                   mortality = rbinom(100, 1, rep(c(0.5, 0.05), each = 500)),
                   condition = rep(c("Sick", "Well"), each = 500))

cox4 <- coxph(Surv(LOS, mortality) ~ condition, data = data)
```

We get the following error when we try to plot:

```
ggforest(cox4)
#> Warning in .get_data(model, data = data): The `data` argument is not provided.
#> Data will be extracted from model fit.
#> Error in .get_data(model, data = data): The `data` argument should be provided
#> either to ggsurvfit or survfit.
```

This is a strange error. It seems to occur because your data frame is called `data`, which is used as a parameter name in `ggforest`. We can make the error go away if we specifically pass `data = data` to `ggforest`:

```
ggforest(cox4, data = data)
```

[image]

or change the name of your data frame:

```r
df <- data

cox4 <- coxph(Surv(LOS, mortality) ~ condition, data = df)

ggforest(cox4)
#> Warning in .get_data(model, data = data): The `data` argument is not provided.
#> Data will be extracted from model fit.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, when I try with the code you have above, I get the same column error (just renamed dataframe to ABC). 
> 
> cox4 <- coxph(Surv(LOS, mortality) ~ condition, data = ABC)
> ggforest(cox4)
Error in `[.data.frame`(cbind(allTermsDF, coef[inds, ]), , c("var", "level",  : 
  undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In .get_data(model, data = data) :
  The `data` argument is not provided. Data will be extracted from model fit.

Comment: @ABC did you try `ggforest(cox4, data = ABC)`?

Comment: Yes -- then I get just the undefined column error: 

> ggforest(cox4,data=ABC)
Error in `[.data.frame`(cbind(allTermsDF, coef[inds, ]), , c("var", "level",  : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @ABC and if you run the model with just a single variable do you get the same error? If not, is there one particular variable that breaks it?

Comment: I did try this -- if run my own model with just 1 variable, it gives the same error, similar as with your code above with the variable "condition". If it helps, I am running R 4.0.2, survminer 0.4.7, and survival 3.2-3.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. And I solved it by replacing the R package of "broom" with a previous version.

Comment: It would probably help future viewers of the answer if the relevant versions of `broom` are stated and an explanation of how or why this answered the original question.

Comment: How do I install an older version of broom?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same Problem when using `as.factor()` within the `coxph`-function:

```
cox0x<-coxph(formula=Surv(SurvTime.full,state.full=="1") ~  as.factor(PreSur), data=data1)
ggforest(cox0x, data=data1)

Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : undefined columns selected
```

Of note, my variable `PreSur` already was a factor when used in `coxph`.
However, when avoiding `as.factor()` in my case solved the Problem:

```
cox0x<-coxph(formula=Surv(SurvTime.full,state.full=="1") ~  PreSur, data=data1)
ggforest(cox0x, data=data1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBpAU.png)

However, I am aware that this is not the solution to ABC's problem, who does not use `as.factor()` in the code. It might be helpful to others though....